# Listview design with in two section

Tags: android, user-interface, listview, android-listview

Is there any default way to design listview into two section with different viewitems? Both section must increase height according to content and each section should be able to hide idependantly .The example of listview I am talking about is like given in below image

First I thought to take two listview saperated by textview in one parent scrollview but then I realised two listview will have two independent scrollview. but I need only one scrollview for both section. so how to achieve such gui given below? Don't need code. Just want hint. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `getItemViewTypeCount()` in your adapter to return 2 in your case if you want 2 different types of views.

Override `getItemViewType(int pos)` to tell your adapter's `getView(...)` how to treat different views.

Create two different view holders.

Finally in your `getView(...)` after querying the view type (by mentioning it in your model) inflate the corresponding view and instantiate the corresponding view holder and voila you're done.

Also refer to some examples of view holder pattern in list views if something is not clear.

Comment: each section should be able to hide idependantly!---Any Idea how to do that?

Comment: To toggle visibility of each row independently if some condition is met in the model just return an empty view that should work.

Comment: and How can I put a textview between two sections in the listview?

Comment: that is your second view type you can set a flag for it in your list of models that you pass to your adapter to recognize it in your getView().

Comment: @Kevan, Just create a third type of view which you use as your separator.

Comment: from the picture you posted it basically has two different view types one is with checkbox, text view and an optional imageView (for the drawable) and the other is just the textview with a transparent background to it.